# How do I check the initiale state of ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two `toggleButton's`, both set to `null` state, now I want to check if the user ever toggled the button or not.

```
<StackPanel Height="45" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
<Label VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Content="هل القاعة صالحة من حيث الإستماع؟"/>
<ToggleButton x:Name="ListeningStatusText" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{x:Null}" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Height="45" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
<Label VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Content="الإضاءة"/>
<ToggleButton x:Name="LightingStatusText" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{x:Null}" />
</StackPanel>
```

With the code bellow I failled to see if the user never toggle the button:

```
var ToggleButtonControl = (ToggleButton)ControlName; // 
if (ToggleButtonControl.IsChecked == null)
{
    parameterStr = "/////////////";
    //MessageBox.Show("This should pop-up only if the user never toggled the button");
}
else
{
    //MessageBox.Show("The user toggle or toggle it back");
    if (ToggleButtonControl.IsChecked == false)
        parameterStr = "لا";
    else
        parameterStr = "نعم";
}
```

Comment: It seems to work for me.  If toggle button not clicked, IsChecked will be null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the use has ever toggled the button, attach a function to the Checked and Unchecked event and have a Boolean flag in your class to track that.

The button would look something like this (plus your other attributes):

```
<ToggleButton
Checked="toggleButton_Changed"
Unchecked="toggleButton_Changed" />
```

In the function body, set the boolean flag to true, meaning the user has toggled your button. If you want to get the current value, check the button's IsChecked property.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in property that you can use to determine whether a `ToggleButton` has even been toggled. The users can toggle between the `true`, `false` and `null` states as many times they want.

You will need to keep track of this yourself. This should be an easy thing to do though. You could for example handle the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events as suggested by @pedrolmota and use a field to keep track of whether these event handlers were ever called:

```
private bool _hasBeenToggled;
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _hasBeenToggled = true;
}

private void ToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _hasBeenToggled = true;
}
```

You then simply check the value of the field in your other method:

```
var ToggleButtonControl = (ToggleButton)ControlName; // 
if (!_hasBeenToggled) //<--
{
    parameterStr = "/////////////";
    //MessageBox.Show("This should pop-up only if the user never toggled the button");
}
else
{
    //MessageBox.Show("The user toggle or toggle it back");
    if (ToggleButtonControl.IsChecked == false)
        parameterStr = "لا";
    else
        parameterStr = "نعم";
}
```

If you follow the MVVM design pattern, you could just set the `_hasBeenToggled` in the setter of your source property.